# delete_dir() from Codeigniter doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory

I get this error message when I try to delete a directory:

> "Unable to delete the file" using PHP Codeigniter's delete_dir('/path/to/my/dir/'). No additional info provided.

There is no problem with the *ftp* conn (works with everything else), no problem with the file permission (`delete_file()` works jsut fine)..no problem with the code, the path is also valid. I'm all out of ideas and open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unlink()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) to remove php directory.

```
  function removedir($dir1) { 
  if (is_dir($dir1)) { 
  //scan
 $files = scandir($dir1); 
 //loop through all the files
 foreach ($files as $file) { 
   if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
     if (filetype($dir1."/".$file) == "dir1") 
      rrmdir($dir1."/".$file); 
     else  
      unlink($dir1."/".$file); 
   } 
 } 
 reset($files); 
 rmdir($dir); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rorschach, but I see that "The directory must be empty".. so this doesn't help me because it's not